# Spring Cloud Stream: Proper handling for StreamListener when it takes a long time to process the message

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

When StreamListener is taking a long time (longer than `max.poll.interval.ms`) to process a message, thus that particular consumer is occupied and other new messages will be assigned to other partitions. After the time is greater than `max.poll.interval.ms`, rebalance happened and the same situation will happened to another consumer. So this message will circulate around all the partitions and keep on hogging the resources.

However, this situation is not happening very often, only a few messages somehow is taking such a long time to process and it's uncontrollable.

Can we commit the offset and throw it to DLQ after a few times of rebalancing? If yes, how can we do that? If no, what's the proper handling for this kind of situation?

Comment: Why not just increase `max.poll.interval.ms` ?

Comment: Because this msg could take very long time to process but this is not the norm. I don't want to sacrifice the performance just to cover this kind of message. I would like to ignore it and then just proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing `max.poll.interval.ms` will have no impact on performance (except it will take longer to detect a consumer that is **really** dead).

Going through a rebalance each time you process this "bad" record is much more damaging to performance.

You can, however, do what you want with a custom [`SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` together with a recoverer such as the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#seek-to-current). You would also need a rebalance listener to count the rebalances and some mechanism to share the state from the error handler across instances (the standard one only keeps state in memory).

Quite complicated, I think.